# how to suppress thousands of lines of informational logs when running tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

When I run a LSTM model constructed by tensorflow, thousands of lines of informational logs are printed in the command window. How to suppress these informational logs?
[These are logs printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf4fo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `log_device_placement=false` in ConfigProto

Comment: Thanks! I see, these logs are device allocation information.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase your min log level to filter out less relevant information, e.g

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
```

For the record, use

- '1' to filter out 'I' (info) messages (your case)
- '2' to further filter out 'W' (warning) messages
- '3' to further filter our 'E' (error) messages, leaving logging open only for 'F' (fatal) messages.